# Consume WCF service in xcode 5 and ios 7

Tags: wcf, ios7, xcode5

I have created a WCF Service to insert data in sql server, so that why I have followed the below structure.

I created first the method and his Implementation;

In WCF interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    UriTemplate = "json/InsertEmployee/{id1}/{id2}/{id3}")]
bool InsertEmployeeMethod(string id1,string id2, string id3);
```

In Implementation:

```
    public bool InsertEmployeeMethod(string id1, string id2, string id3)
    {

        int success = 0;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=NXT1;User ID=zakaria;Password=11;Initial Catalog=EmpDB;Integrated Security=false"))
        {
            conn.Open();

            decimal value = Decimal.Parse(id3);
            string cmdStr = string.Format("INSERT INTO EmpInfo VALUES('{0}','{1}',{2})", id1, id2, value);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn);
            success = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn.Close();
        }

        return (success != 0 ? true : false);
    }
```

to test the web service, try that URL:

```
"41.142.251.142/JsonWcfService/GetEmployees.svc/json/InsertEmployee/myName/MylastName/6565"
```

until here all is working well,

So to test this web servcie, I created in my Main.storyboard 3 textFields (firstName.text and lastName.text and salary.text and a button to send the data entered). note that I have worked with xcode 5 and ios 7.

I declared the url inside my viewcontroller.m as following:
myViewController.m:

```
#define BaseWcfUrl [NSURL URLWithString:@"41.142.251.142/JsonWcfService/GetEmployees.svc/json/InsertEmployee/{id1}/{id2}/{id3}"]
```

Then I implemented the Insert Employee Method related to click button.

```
-(void) insertEmployeeMethod

{

if(firstname.text.length && lastname.text.length && salary.text.length)

{

NSString *getValue= [BaseWcfUrl stringByAppendingFormat:@"InsertEmployee/%@/%@/%@",firstname.text,lastname.text,salary.text];

NSURL *WcfServiceURL = [NSURL URLWithString:getValue];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:WcfServiceURL];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// connect to the web

NSData *respData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

// NSString *respStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:respData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSError *error;

NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization 

                      JSONObjectWithData:respData 

                      options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 

                      error:&error];  



NSNumber *isSuccessNumber = (NSNumber*)[json objectForKey:@"InsertEmployeeMethodResult"];
    }

}
```

So the issue that I have encountered is that the system always return the str value as "Nil"

```
NSString *getValue= [BaseWcfUrl stringByAppendingFormat:@"InsertEmployee/%@/%@/%@",firstname.text,lastname.text,salary.text];
```

so you can see all the message error here :

> 2014-02-17 19:49:49.419 InsertData[2384:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>
> 0   CoreFoundation                      0x017395e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
>
> 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014bc8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
>
> 2   CoreFoundation                      0x017393bb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
>
> 3   Foundation                          0x012037a2 +[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:options:error:] + 67
>
> 4   InsertData                          0x0000236c -[ViewController sendData:] + 1452
>
> 5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014ce874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
>
> 6   UIKit                               0x0022c0c2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
>
> 7   UIKit                               0x0022c04e -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
>
> 8   UIKit                               0x003240c1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
>
> 9   UIKit                               0x00324484 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
>
> 10  UIKit                               0x00323733 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
>
> 11  UIKit                               0x0026951d -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
>
> 12  UIKit                               0x0026a184 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1232
>
> 13  UIKit                               0x0023de86 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
>
> 14  UIKit                               0x0022818f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
>
> CoreFoundation                      0x016c283f **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 15
>
> 16  CoreFoundation                      0x016c21cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
>
> 17  CoreFoundation                      0x016df29e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
>
> 18  CoreFoundation                      0x016deac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
>
> 19  CoreFoundation                      0x016de8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
>
> 20  GraphicsServices                    0x036de9e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
>
> 21  GraphicsServices                    0x036de809 GSEventRun + 104
>
> 22  UIKit                               0x0022ad3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
>
> 23  InsertData                          0x00002d5d main + 141
>
> 24  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d7770d start + 1
>
> )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

can you please help me on that, i'm very stressed with.

much appreciate .

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have the wrong URL, you're adding `InsertEmployee` twice.

Change `BaseWcfUrl`  to just `[NSURL URLWithString:@"41.142.251.142/JsonWcfService/GetEmployees.svc/json/"]` instead of `[NSURL URLWithString:@"41.142.251.142/JsonWcfService/GetEmployees.svc/json/InsertEmployee/{id1}/{id2}/{id3}"]`

To be absolutely sure, log the final URL to the console (or look at it in the debugger) to make sure it's correct.

Also, in your code, in `NSURL *WcfServiceURL = [NSURL URLWithString:str];`, where is `str` coming from? Did you mean `getValue` there?

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, I have edited the str to getValue.
I will do what you suggest, and go back to you

Comment: I changed BaseWcfUrl to the URL "[NSURL URLWithString:@"41.142.251.142/JsonWcfService/GetEmployees.svc/json/"]"

Comment: I changed BaseWcfUrl to the URL "[NSURL URLWithString:@"41.142.251.142/JsonWcfService/GetEmployees.svc/json/"]"
but now the system appears another error; 
[NSURL stringByAppendingFormat:]:unrecognized selector sent to the instance 0x8a630b0.
terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException','reason :'-[NSURL stringByAppendingFormat :]: unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x8a630b0